# IEEE Communication letters template

Tags: pdftex, templates

I am trying to get the Latex template for IEEE Communication Letters. The IEEE website does not seem to have the specific pdftex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Googling for `IEEE communication letters template` leads you to https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType, where you can select the template.

Comment: The site does not have a specific Letter template

Comment: Sometimes if you just pretend that you have the manuscript ready and initiate   the submission process whatsoever, there will be something like *double check if your manuscript is typeset using our official class file https://...*.

Comment: That said, it's not your fault. IEEE is good at hiding things. Plus they have so many sub-communities that never talk to each other and develop their own unspoken rules. Hence the one-for-all template is very vague. I myself do not see how to cite a grant, which is arguably the most important component of a paper.

Answer (score 2):

1. Google for `IEEE communication letters template`
2. The first result Google shows me is [IEEE Communications Letters Submit a Manuscript](https://www.comsoc.org/publications/journals/ieee-comml/ieee-communications-letters-submit-manuscript)
3. Scroll down to `Submission Format`. The first paragraph contains a link to [IEEE style files](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html).
4. You arrive at the page `IEEE Article Templates`. The second paragraph starts with a link to the [IEEE Template Selector](https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType).
5. Click on the button (box) labeled `Transactions, Journals and Letters`.
6. From the drop-down menu called `Select name of the publication`, choose `IEEE Communications Letters`.
7. On the new page, select the single button (box) `Original research and Brief`.
8. On the next page, select the button (box) `LaTeX`.
9. The next page tells you `Your requested template is available below`. Click on the blue button `Download Template`. This downloads the archive `IEEE-Transactions-LaTeX2e-templates-and instructions.zip`. (I cannot link to this zip archive, as it is not a normal link but some script that downloads the file.)

This is all the information that IEEE thinks you need for formatting a manuscript. It doesn't include a class file, as `IEEEtran.cls` is part of the standard TeX distributions. Try to typeset the two sample documents. If it doesn't work, you probably have to update your TeX distribution.

If there are still problems, you will have to contact the editor or the journal for further help.